# como ingresar datos a cola.nuevocliente(c,urg)

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

```
package colaprioridad;

import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class Colaprioridad {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PriorityQueue pq = new PriorityQueue();
        Cliente c = new Cliente("Andy", 5, 30);
        Urgencia urg = new Urgencia("baja");
        Colaurgencia cola = new Colaurgencia();
        System.out.println("Ingresar nuevo cliente");

        cola.nuevoCliente(c, urg);
        cola.numClientesEnEspera();

        cola.muestraEstado();

    }
```

Estuve buscando temas de herencias, objetos. Pero aún no logro entender de que es lo que debería ir dentro de esos paréntesis para que se pueda mostrar los datos que quiero.

Comment: Puedes poner las clases, en especial la de Colaurgencia para ver en que esta fallando

Comment: Hola Bryan, supongo que dentro de la clase Colaurgencia debes tener una estructura de tipo Map u otras estructuras ArrayList, pero para poder ayudarte, tienes que ponernos el codigo de Colaurgencia. Saludos.